# How can this verbose jQuery be elegantized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 rows that each have an identical selection element (or dropDownList) in the first cell of each row. Choosing a value from that populates the values in another selection element.

How can I populate the selection items, and in a way that is less verbose than the "brute force" approach here:

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPaymentType1]', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == '1') {
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection 1");
    }
    else if (value == '2') {{
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection 2");
    }
    else if (value == '3') {{
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection 3");
    }
    else if (value == '4') {{
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection 4");
    }
    else if (value == '5') {{
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection 5");
    }
    else if (value == '6') {{
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection 6");
    }
    /* TODO: Add the rest (not value=11, as that is the "VENDORS" category item (not a real selection in itself)) */
});
```

With the above, I would have to respond to about 20 different values (only six are shown), and I would have to five identical-except-for-the-ID-and-args functions. IOW, I would also need

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPaymentType2]', function () {
    . . .
});
```

...etc (up through ddlPaymentType5).

What is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is probably a better question for Code Review, unless you have something that isn't working here.

Comment: But I would also try a switch statement.

Comment: Yes, it's not working; at least now it's not; see the Update.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon updated answer. Sloppy object model.

Comment: Thanks; I'll check it Monday. Say hi to Dean for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do for example something like this:

```
var selects = { "1": [
                        ["value 1", "text 1"], 
                        ["value 2", "text 2"]
                      ]
               ,"2": [
                        ["value 1", "text 1"], 
                        ["value 2", "text 2"]
                      ]
               , /* Rest of your values here */
};

var $select = $('[id$=ddlAccount1]');
$select.children().remove();

var options = selects[$(this).val()];

options.forEach(function(item) {
  $select.append($("<option />").val(item[0]).text(item[1]));
});
```

http://jsbin.com/wukovavupe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Looks good so far, but how can I add N items to the select / DropDownList elements (not just one string)?

Comment: So what you want to do is insert options in a `select` based on the value from another `select`?

Comment: Exactly: selecting one category will determine what options appear in a related dropdownllist.

Comment: I was so sure that was going to work, that I marked it as the answer, but then in actuality it fails with an err msg, so I've (temporarily) unmarked it. I will give the details of the error encountered in Update 4.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon sorry, but my code works and your original question has been answered. Check the JSBin, it works fine. If you're still having trouble with debugging your application, [consider asking a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) or hiring a senior Javascript professional.

Comment: No, I had to add a declaration for "options"; see my Answer below. My bad - you had that, I see; somehow it get stripped out/removed betwixt the cup and the lip.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for..?

```
 $(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPaymentType1]', function () {
      var value = $(this).val();        
        $('[id$=ddlAccount1]').text("Replace this with the values for selection " + value);                   
        /* TODO: Add the rest (not value=11, as that is the "VENDORS" category item (not a real selection in itself)) */
    });
```

Comment: A good starting point. But maybe you can generalise the script even more in a way that it will be applicable for all of your five rows with a similar situation. This can be done by selecting the target elements through a relative selector (searching relative to `$(this)` with `.siblings()` or `.parents()`). That way a single function could take care of all your update requirements.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Jan above (as in above this answer on this page, not as in one who resides in the heavens) and from "jakecigar" over on the jQuery forums, plus an "add-back" of my own (var options = selects[$(this).val()];) whose omission was causing errors, this is what I'm using as a starting point now:

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPaymentType1]', function () {
    var selects = [
    [
        ["value 1", "text 1"],
        ["value 2", "text 2"]
    ],
    [
        ["value 1", "text 1"],
        ["value 2", "text 2"]
    ]
    /* Rest of your values here */
  ]

  var $select = $('[id$=ddlAccount1]');
  $select.empty();

  var options = selects[$(this).val()];

  console.log(options, $select)

  $.each(options, function (i, item) {
  console.log(item)
  $select.append($("<option />", {
      value: item[0],
      text: item[1]
    }))
  });        
});
```